# How to back up ringtones on cloud in windows 10 mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sync, backup, microsoft-account, ringtone

I have many custom ringtones from many apps some of which have been pulled from the store while some ringtones belong to deleted audio files. So, is there anyway that I can get those ringtones backed up onto my outlook account and get them all on a new device as well when I sign in with my account on that device? If not, is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

If you create custom ringtones in Windows Phones, whether using the Ringtone Maker app, or the traditional method of copying **.mp3** files, they are stored on the phone in a folder named "Ringtones":

[image]

So, if you want to move the ringtones to another device, you can just copy the contents of the folder, onto your machine, then drop them in the same folder on the other phone. You can just store them on your compute, and then move them to the other device when you want.

Comment: But @kelvinelove The ringtones which I ahve added through apps do not appear in Ringtones folder.